# TextButton Icon with Two Line Label/Text, Is it possible?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

Trying to make a card menu that is a quick link to app's main sections. I tried using TextButton.Icon ( but since the word count varies too much from 8-letter word to 19-letter word, the font size becomes too small for the shorter word, so the aesthetics looks weird.

I'm thinking to make the label of the button to two lines as shown in the JPEG attached.
[image]

Wondering if this is possible with a container inside a material button instead?

```js
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class QuickMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  const QuickMenu({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false, //to remove back button
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4.0, 25.0, 4.0, 3.0),
            height: 55.0,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Image(
                  image: AssetImage('images/logo.png'),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.notifications_outlined,
                    size: 35.0,
                    color: Color(0xFF959DA8),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Card(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0),
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding:
                            const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 5.0, 15.0, 3.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'MENU BUTTONS',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Roboto",
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            color: Color(0xFFD4D7DA),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            TextButton.icon(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              icon: Icon(Icons.home,
                                  color: Colors.white, size: 30.0),
                              label: Text(
                                'Text Button 1',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                    fontSize: 15.0,
                                    color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                padding:
                                    EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 8.0, 20.0, 8.0),
                                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFD4D7DA),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 10.0,
                            ),
                            TextButton.icon(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              icon: Icon(Icons.home,
                                  color: Colors.white, size: 30.0),
                              label: Text(
                                'Text Button 2',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                    fontSize: 15.0,
                                    color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                padding:
                                    EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 8.0, 75.0, 8.0),
                                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFD4D7DA),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 8.0),
                        child: Expanded(
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              TextButton.icon(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                icon: Icon(Icons.home,
                                    color: Colors.white, size: 30.0),
                                label: Text(
                                  'Text Button 3',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                      fontSize: 8.0,
                                      color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                  padding:
                                      EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 8.0, 20.0, 8.0),
                                  backgroundColor: Color(0xFFD4D7DA),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 10.0,
                              ),
                              TextButton.icon(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                icon: Icon(Icons.home,
                                    color: Colors.white, size: 30.0),
                                label: Text(
                                  'Text Button 4',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                      fontSize: 8.0,
                                      color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                  padding:
                                      EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 8.0, 75.0, 8.0),
                                  backgroundColor: Color(0xFFD4D7DA),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this and also if you used a list or column you can make it expanded

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class QuickMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  const QuickMenu({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false, //to remove back button
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4.0, 25.0, 4.0, 3.0),
            height: 55.0,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Image(
                  image: AssetImage('images/profile.png'),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.notifications_outlined,
                    size: 35.0,
                    color: Color(0xFF959DA8),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Card(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0),
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              color: Colors.grey,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding:
                              const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 5.0, 15.0, 3.0),
                          child: Text(
                            'MENU BUTTONS',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: "Roboto",
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              color: Color(0xFFD4D7DA),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        TextButton.icon(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                          label: Container(
                            width: 100,// change width as you need
                            height: 70, // change height as you need
                            child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Text(
                                "Text",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                maxLines: 2, // change max line you need
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                            padding:
                            EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 8.0, 20.0, 8.0),
                            backgroundColor: Color(0xFFD4D7DA),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 10,),
                        TextButton.icon(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          icon: Icon(Icons.payments_rounded),
                          label: Container(
                            width: 100, // change width as you need
                            height: 70, // change height as you need
                            child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Text(
                                "Text Button 2",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                maxLines: 2,
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),// change max line you need
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                            padding:
                            EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 8.0, 20.0, 8.0),
                            backgroundColor: Color(0xFFD4D7DA),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        TextButton.icon(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                          label: Container(
                            width: 100,
                            height: 70, // change height as you need
                            child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Text(
                                "TextButton 3  ",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                maxLines: 2, // change max line you need
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                            padding:
                            EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 8.0, 20.0, 8.0),
                            backgroundColor: Color(0xFFD4D7DA),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 10,),
                        TextButton.icon(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
                          label: Container(
                            width: 100, // change width as you need
                            height: 70, // change height as you need
                            child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Text(
                                "TextButton 4",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                maxLines: 2, // change max line you need
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                            padding:
                            EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 8.0, 20.0, 8.0),
                            backgroundColor: Color(0xFFD4D7DA),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

output:
[image]

Comment: can you change it? otherwise i will fix it

Comment: hi @Jahidul, thanks for the quick reply... really appreciate it. :) The 4 buttons though will have different icons (example only: Cart, Account, Payment, Bill). So I think the widget code for the icons cannot work? Also, the Icon and Label will be aligned left instead of centered. Thanks again.

Comment: updated my answer, but if you want dynamic you must need to expand you row item and I think you change rest of think as you need

Comment: hello @Jahidul, your suggested answer worked. Thank you so much. ヽ(*´∀)ﾉﾟ

Comment: What do you mean by  "but if you want dynamic you must need to expand you row item"? Can you show me?

Answer (score 1):

Just simply use column widget in the label

```
            TextButton.icon(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: const Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.white, size: 30.0),
          label: Column(
            children: const [
              Text(
                'Text Button Title',
                style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Roboto', fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.white),
              ),
              Text(
                'Text Button Subtitle',
                style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Roboto', fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 8.0, 20.0, 8.0),
            backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFD4D7DA),
          ),
        ),
```

**OR**

You can simply use Row widget

```
            InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 8.0, 20.0, 8.0),
            color: const Color(0xFFD4D7DA),
            child: Row(
              children: const [
                Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.white, size: 30.0),
                SizedBox(width: 12),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    'Text Button 1',
                    softWrap: true,
                    style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Roboto', fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

To create UI like this, you just need to follow these steps:

1. Take a Column widget.
2. Inside column, take a **Align(alignment:Alignment.left, child: Text("Menu Buttons")** )
3. After that take two Rows

```
Row(children: [
                          Container(
                              height: 60,
                              width: 100,
                              child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [Icon(Icons.add), Text("Text")])),
                          Container(
                              height: 60,
                              width: 100,
                              child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [Icon(Icons.add), Text("Text")])),
                        ]),
```